# How do I remove copies of GHC that were installed by Stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Like the poster in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/46reio/how_to_uninstall_snapshots_and_older_ghc_from/?st=j5veogfw&sh=24d5685e), I am running low on drive space and would like to get rid of some of the older versions of GHC that Stack installed for me. (I have five versions installed and they’re taking up over 6 GB.) Is it safe just to remove the individual versions’ folders from `~/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx`, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, deleting those directories is safe.